# how to automatically retrieve the request URL (for python) from an XHR request of a page loaded via JavaScript

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Here is the URL that I'm trying to **scrape**: https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm

I'm trying to **scrape** the webpage using Python which mean I will require the XHR request for this page as it is loaded via JavaScript.

Upon inspection of the Network under Developer Tools, I can see the XHR request: a10-qq320196292019.htm which produces the request URL: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm

My question is two-fold,

1. How can I automatically get this request URL if i am only accessing using the URL given initially and,
2. How do I know that this is THE XHR request I need? This particular URL works for my needs but I noticed that there were many other XHR reqeusts as well. How does one differentiate?

Comment: For the answer to the first question, use a headless browser like Selenium.  For the second question, give an example.  Usually the XHR that includes `/edgar/data/` should be the right one

Comment: FYi it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you need to go that route. The link you're using [is an ixbrl view of the actual html document.](https://www.datatracks.co.uk/ixbrl-blog/what-is-ixbrl/) The url for the html doc is embedded in that first link. All you have to do is extract it:

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm'
html_url = url.replace('/ix?doc=','')
html_url
```

Output:

> 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000076/a10-qq320196292019.htm